# On current enclosed by Ameprian loop

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

Ampère’s law is saying :
$$\oint \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{dl} = \mu_{0}I_{inc} $$

Where $$I_{inc} = \int \mathbf J \cdot \mathbf {da}  $$

But if my Amperian loop encloses a wire at an angle :

[image]

**What is $I_{inc}$ equal to in the case where the wire is one dimensional ? is it $I$ or $I\cos \theta $ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had a uniform current density and your wire had a cross-sectional area $\vec{A}$. The magnitude of $\vec{J}$ is I/A.

Now move to your Amperian loop and suppose for the sake of this argument that it bounds a flat surface which cuts the wire at an angle $\theta$ as shown in your diagram. The current density is now at an angle $\theta$ to the area vector defined by the Amperian loop and the size of this area vector is $A'$. Note that $A' > A$, because you have cut the wire at an angle. In fact $A' = A/\cos \theta$. Thus when you do the scalar product
$$\int \vec{J}\cdot d\vec{a} = \frac{I}{A}A'\cos\theta = I$$

Comment: Can you provide a proof for the claim that $A' = A/\cos \theta$ for every flat surface ?

Comment: What do you mean by every flat surface? You mean if (for example) I have a circular cross-section and I cut it at an angle theta, why is the area of the ellipse so formed $A/\cos \theta$ ? @O.Orenstein

Comment: Just imagine little rectangles with dimension $x$ and $y$. If I project that through an angle $\theta$ then *one* of the dimensions becomes a the hypoteneuse of a right angle triangle of length $x/\cos\theta$ and the other is unchanged. The area increases as $xy/\cos\theta$ and any area can be made up of infinitesimally small rectangles. @O.Orenstein Just draw a side view of your wire and see.

Comment: Great explanation ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RobJeffries So the field will be the same even if the wire is almost parallel to the loop? What if the angle is 90 degrees?

Comment: Ampere's law does not tell you what the field is; it tells you what the closed line integral of the field around a particular path is. @Nasu. If it is 89.9 degrees then the enclosed current is $I$. You could not use Ampere's law to tell you the field in such a case because it would not be constant or parallel to the loop you have chosen.

Comment: I did not say that it does.  The point is that the loop integral depends on the angle between the current density and the normal to the plane of the loop.  The notion of "enclosed current" works only for currents perpendicular to the loop.  Otherwise you have to use the general form.

Comment: Well @nasu there are three answers that disagree with you, and I have shown why what I say is true. You can also look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252907/amperes-law-and-stokes-theorem-for-current-density?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is $I$.  The current $\int {\bf j}\cdot {\bf da}$ is a scalar. You can't take its components because it does not have any.

The cosine has already been taken care of in computing the scalar product $ {\bf j}\cdot {\bf da}$.

Comment: Is it $I$ also in the case where the wire is 3 dimensional (meaning it has non-zero cross section area and finite $\mathbf J$)  ?

Comment: Yes.   That's what the $\int {\bf j}\cdot {\bf da}$ is for.

Comment: The "da" here is area element of the loop and not of the conductor. In general you don't even need a conductor. You can just have some charges moving through the loop and creating a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

The, I, does not change. The, B, field produced by a current in a long wire has no component parallel to the wire.  The cosine comes from the dot product of, B, with,  dl, (giving the component of, dl, which is parallel with, B).

Comment: But the line integral around a loop does depend on the angle between the wire and the loop. And this is what Ampere's law is about.

Comment: The line integral around the loop depends on the angle between each segment of the loop and the B field.